# Sharepoint 2010 DBs SAN issue

Tags: service-application

SharePoint 2010  All Databases are moved from one Storage(i.e., A) to another storage(i.e., B).

Note: Already SharePoint working with storage A properly. Due to storage A  expiration , we plan to move New Storage B

Note: 2 App Server,2 wfe and 1 Sql CULSTER(node 1 and node 2)

here my query is, during mapping the Storage B(mean bring online storage B database)any impact in SharePoint Central admin and Portal functionalities(search,web part,UI and Datas).

Please list out  all possible impacts during storage B mapping ?

Thanks,
P.Mohan

Answer (score 2):

Moving the database files in the cluster is purely a SQL Server issue. SharePoint has no knowledge and don't care where the database files are stored. It only knows and cares about being able to connect to a SQL server using the name/alias it knows and find the databases with the names it knows. Where the two SQL servers stores the files is something only they know and care about.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple - if SQL is unavailable during the move, then the SharePoint farm will be unavailable. I suggest working with your DBA team to minimise any downtime.